# How to select a web form option based on a value from a column in a dataframe using Selenium

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please I have a Selenium script that I use to autofill data into a web form. One of the fields called **location** is a selection field. I would like to match the value in a column to the index of the web form before selecting it. For example, I want to select index 9 on the webform based on a column value of 9.

**What I have done**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

for i in range(1,10):    

    add_event_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="tab-voyage-log-12910"]/div[2]/a[2]'))).click()
    time.sleep(1)

date_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//*[@id='WGItem02_voyage_log-{i}_4']")))
    date_field.send_keys(date_time_row[i-1])
    time.sleep(1)
    
                    
    location_field = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[@id='WGItem09_voyage_log-{i}_4']"))
    
    location_field.select_by_index(8)
    time.sleep(1)
    
            
    event_field = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[@id='WGItem04_voyage_log-{i}_4']"))
    event_field.select_by_index(4)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    subevent_field = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[@id='WGItem05_voyage_log-{i}_4']"))
    subevent_field.select_by_index(3)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    remarks_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//*[@id='WGItem06_voyage_log-{i}_4']")))
    remarks_field.send_keys(remarks_data_col[i-1])
    time.sleep(2)
```

So, instead of selecting **index 8** from the *location_field*, I want to select an option based on a column value from a data frame.

*Here is my dataFrame for the input fields above:*

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = "example.xls"


df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, header = 0, usecols = "A,B,D,E,H")

df['DateAndTime'] = df['Date'].str.cat(df['Time'],sep=" ")

date_time_data = df['DateAndTime']
date_time_row = date_time_data.iloc

df['activity_comments'] = df['Activity Comments']
remarks_data = df['activity_comments']
remarks_data_col = remarks_data.iloc

df['location_index'] = df['Location_ID']
locations_data = df['location_index']
```

**Column D** contains the index value (eg. 9) which needs to be selected on the **Location** field.
Please for the **location_field** variable, I want to select an option based on the row value from *column D*.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked is not different from what was done with the **remarks_field** variable.

Here is how I formatted the **location_field** variable with the Select class.

```
location_field = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f"//*[@id='WGItem09_voyage_log-{i}_4']"))
    location_field.select_by_index(locations_data_col[i-1])
    time.sleep(1)
```

Since the *locations_data_col* contains the value that is parsed into the Select class which selects the index from the web form field.